# Incrementing dates with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm trying to create an array of blackout dates for a reservation system in Laravel 4.  There is one test row in my db with a start_date of 2016-01-24 and end_date of 2016-01-29.

This is the code that pulls the row and loops through the dates using Carbon to increment by one day & add it to an array:

```
$reserved = Reservation::where('property_id', $property->id)->get();

$blackoutDays = [];

foreach($reserved as $r)
{
    $start = new \Carbon\Carbon($r->start_date);
    $end = new \Carbon\Carbon($r->end_date);
    $days = $start->diff($end)->days;

    for($i = 0; $i <= $days; $i++)
    {
        $date = '';
        $date = $start->addDays($i);

        $blackoutDays[] = $date->format('Y-m-j');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to get in $blackoutDays is:

> ["2016-01-24", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-26", "2016-01-27", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-29"]

But what I'm actually getting is this:

> ["2016-01-24", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-27", "2016-01-30", "2016-02-3", "2016-02-8"]

Does anyone know why this is happening / how to fix it?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You do increment `$i` every run of your for loop. So it adds 1 in the first run, 2 days in the second, 3 days in the third and so on.

Therefore, you want to replace

```
$date = $start->addDays($i);
```

with

```
$date = $start->addDays(1);
```

Where you probably fell into the pit is the idea that the days are added from the `$start` date object on every call, but this is not the case, as this object is not "[Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)".

Comment: thanks, works perfectly!  Now I'm gonna go hide until I stop feeling like a noob!

Answer (score 5):

For more cleaner result, you can use addDay() method:

```
$date = $start->addDay();
```

But in fact this is exactly the same. Source code for addDay() method:

```
/**
 * Add a day to the instance
 *
 * @param int $value
 *
 * @return static
 */
public function addDay($value = 1)
{
    return $this->addDays($value);
}
```